# interface between the Quandl financial database and Octave

Tags: octave, quandl

I'm using Octave 4.2.1 and trying to import financial data into Octave. Following these instructions from Quandl site:
 https://github.com/tradingjunkie/OctaveQuandlInterface

> addpath('/path/to/OctaveQuandlInterface') **--Ok**

and  I start by defining an Octave structure

> Quandl.auth = token;**--NOK**
>   I got this message: "error: 'token' undefined near line 1 column 15"

Some help please.

Regards

Matt

Comment: there's a hint in the source code that the token is effectively something you need to have from Quandl (apparently from here: https://www.quandl.com/account/ )

Comment: OK,  I continue > data = getQuandl('GOOG/NASDAQ_MSFT',token,'cellstr');but now I got :error: package general is not installed
error: called from
    load_packages at line 41 column 7
    pkg at line 411 column 7
    getQuandl at line 25 column 5

Comment: `pkg install -forge general` to install, `pkg load general` to load for use.